# Hibernate envers, post-delete event throws constraint violation exception

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

Project uses Hibernate 3.5, Spring Webflow 2 and Hibernate Envers for auditing. Envers is configured in hibernate.cfg.xml. I have one-to-many relation mapping between entity 'ArticleGroup' and 'Article'. Table 'articles' has a foreign key 'article_group_id' references to the id in table 'article_groups'. In the front-end, when I delete an article, Hibernate Envers throws constraint violation exception for the post-delete event. If I don't use Envers, delete operations work fine. The two entities are defined as follows

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="article_groups")
    @Audited
    public class ArticleGroup implements Serializable {

        @OneToMany(mappedBy="articleGroup", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @OrderBy("id")
        private List<Article> articles;

        // other fields, getters and setters
    }

    @Entity 
    @Table(name="articles")
    @Audited
    public class Article implements Serializable {

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "article_group_id")
        private ArticleGroup articleGroup;

        // other fields, getters, setters
    }
```

Article deletion is coded as follows:

```
    @Service("articleManager")
    public class ArticleManagerImpl implements ArticleManager {
            // inject dao
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
            public void deleteArticle(Article article, Object articles) {
            articleDao.delete(article);
            ((List<Article>)  ((OneSelectionTrackingListDataModel)articles).getWrappedData()).remove(article);
        }
    }
```

The constraint violation exception:

```
Hibernate: delete from live.articles where id=?
Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
Hibernate: insert into audit.REVINFO (REVTSTMP, REV) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into audit.articles_AUD (REVTYPE, content, language, name, order_number, title, article_group_id, id, REV) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
82828 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG   org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager  - Initiating transaction rollback after commit exception
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
...
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 insert into audit.articles_AUD (REVTYPE, content, language, name, order_number, title, article_group_id, id, REV) values ('2', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '14', '17') was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement$BatchResultHandler.handleError(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2619)
```

As you could see, when Envers inserts into table 'audit.articles_AUD', the article_group_id is null which caused the constraint violation. Anybody knows how to fix it? Thank you very much.

Comment: Does `live.articles_AUD.article_group_id` have a constraint on `article_group`, I'd assume?  Or does it have any constraints on the actual `articles` table?  If you're doing a post-delete, and `articles_AUD` has any constraints on `articles`, you'd then be trying to to add an entry into `articles_AUD` for a reference that no longer exists.

Comment: Hi, sorry the audit table name is 'audit.articles_AUD'. It does not have any constraint on the actual articles table. It has only one foreign key pointing to table 'revinfo'.

Comment: What happens if you try to call: insert into audit.articles_AUD (REVTYPE, content, language, name, order_number, title, article_group_id, id, REV) values ('2', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '14', '17') from the DB console? What error do you get?

Answer (score 8):

Got it. Set this property in the configuration file:

```
<prop key="org.hibernate.envers.store_data_at_delete">true</prop>
```

Reference:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/envers/3.6/reference/en-US/html/configuration.html
Table 3.1. Envers Configuration Properties
org.hibernate.envers.store_data_at_delete

Answer (score 7):

If you're doing a post-delete, and `articles_AUD` has any constraints on `articles` or any other entry you're removing during this operation, you'd then be trying to to add an entry into `articles_AUD` with a reference that no longer exists.

As a rule of thumb, we keep references out of audit tables in order to better preserver revision history.  If audit tables contain constraints on non-audit tables then revision history could potentially break if any entry from an audited table is removed.

---

In reference to your solution working when setting `org.hibernate.envers.store_data_at_delete`.

> Should the entity data be stored in the revision when the entity is
>   deleted (**instead of only storing the id and all other properties as
>   null**). This is not normally needed, as the data is present in the
>   last-but-one revision. Sometimes, however, it is easier and more
>   efficient to access it in the last revision (then the data that the
>   entity contained before deletion is stored twice).

This tells me that there are columns in your audit table that are `NOT NULL`, hence the constraint violation, as Envers is trying to insert `null`.  You may want to allow null in your audit tables.

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply. The audit table 'articles_AUD' does not have any constraint on table 'articles'. The only foreign key is pointing to 'revinfo'. Another thing is, why all the values in the insert statement is NULL? I suppose they should contain the deleted article's fields value? Any suggestion? Thanks